# Issues with my code which measures the exection time

Tags: java, sorting, time, execution-time

So, I am trying to measure the execution time of some sorting methods.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...

    MeasureExecutionTime(new Runnable() { public void run() { insertionSort(C); } }, "insertionSort()");
}
```

=====================

```
private static void MeasureExecutionTime(Runnable r, String s)
{
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    try
    {
        r.run();
    }
    finally
    {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
    elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(s + " takes " + elapsedTime + " nano-seconds which is " + formatTime(elapsedTime));
}
```

=====================

```
public static String formatTime(long nanoSeconds)
{
    long hours, minutes, remainder, totalSecondsNoFraction;
    double totalSeconds, seconds;

    totalSeconds = (double) nanoSeconds / 1000000000.0;
    String s = Double.toString(totalSeconds);
    String [] arr = s.split("\\.");
    totalSecondsNoFraction = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
    hours = totalSecondsNoFraction / 3600;
    remainder = totalSecondsNoFraction % 3600;
    minutes = remainder / 60;
    seconds = remainder % 60;
    seconds = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString((long)seconds) + Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(".");
    String sep = "", nextSep = " and ";
    if(seconds > 0)
    {
        if(seconds > 1) result.insert(0, " seconds").insert(0, seconds);
        else result.insert(0, " second").insert(0, seconds);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if(minutes > 0)
    {
        if(minutes > 1) result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " minutes").insert(0, minutes);
        else result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " minute").insert(0, minutes);
        sep = nextSep;
        nextSep = ", ";
    }
    if(hours > 0)
    {
        if(hours > 1) result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " hours").insert(0, hours);
        else result.insert(0, sep).insert(0, " hour").insert(0, hours);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

My problem is:

After run this program, and I enter `int[1000000]` as an input, it executes `insertionSort()` in about 12-13 minutes and then returns:

```
insertionSort() takes 767186856920 nano-seconds which is 12 minutes and 470.18685692 seconds.
```

why it gives 470 seconds? what is wrong in my code?

=========================

**EDIT:**

After replacing `seconds = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString((long)seconds) + Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]));` with `seconds = seconds + Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]);`, the previous issue is gone, but another issue showed up:

```
insertionSort() takes 22864 nano-seconds which is 2.000002864 seconds.
```

It should be `0.000022864 seconds.`

=========================

**EDIT2:**

I might discover the error. when `nanoSeconds` is large, `arr[1]` will be ok but when `nanoSeconds` is small, `arr[1]` will convert to exponential form, i.e `14931 nano-seconds => 4.931E-6 seconds.`. How can I solve this issue?

==========================

**EDIT3:**

Ok, I found the solution:

```
if(arr[1].contains("E")) seconds = Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]);
else seconds += Double.parseDouble("." + arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
seconds = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString((long)seconds) + 
                             Double.parseDouble("0." + arr[1]));
```

Say `seconds` is `12` entering this line and `arr[1]` is `"456"`.  Then

```
seconds = Double.parseDouble("12" + Double.parseDouble("0.456"));
seconds = Double.parseDouble("12" + 0.456);
seconds = Double.parseDouble("12" + "0.456");
seconds = Double.parseDouble("120.456");
seconds = 120.456.
```

Why not just do:

```
seconds = seconds + Double.parseDouble("0." + arr[1]);
```

Comment: Sorry, another issue showed up and I had to unselect this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you are concatenating two string "47" and "0.186...".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
seconds = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString((long)seconds) + Double.parseDouble("0." + arr[1]));
```

The second `parseDouble` is returning "0.18685692". Since `arr[1]` is already the string to the right of the decimal point, just use:

```
seconds = Double.parseDouble(Long.toString((long)seconds) + "." + arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an extra zero when you concatenate the strings.  To avoid this kind of problem it would be better to use a formatter to create you strings. See details here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html.

Also, it always helps to calculate the correct answer by hand. This made the problem much easier to find.